# AES/Rijndael-Decryption in C#, Decryption in JavaScript (Node)

Tags: c#, node.js, encryption

I'm currently facing a problem, where I have to decode encrypted files in a Node-Backend. The encryption code is available in C# and looks in it's basics like

```
private static byte[] DeCrypt(byte[] encdata, string pw)
        {
            RijndaelManaged rd = new RijndaelManaged();
            int rijndaelIvLength = 16;
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] key = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pw));
            md5.Clear();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encdata);
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            ms.Read(iv, 0, rijndaelIvLength);
            rd.IV = iv;
            rd.Key = key;
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rd.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            byte[] data = new byte[ms.Length - rijndaelIvLength + 1];
            int i = cs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            cs.Close();
            rd.Clear();

            rd.Clear();
            return data;
        }
```

encdata are the bytes of the encrypted file, pw is a fixed password. My Node-function (including different attempts of encryption) looks like following:

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
const fs = require('fs');
const converter = require('convert-string');
const Rijndael = require('rijndael-js');
const padder = require('pkcs7-padding');
const crypto = require('crypto');

async function decrypt(filePath, password) {
    const encryptedFile = fs.readFileSync(filePath).buffer;
    const chunks = [];
    for await (let chunk of fs.createReadStream(filePath, { start: 0, end: 15 })) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    }
    const iv = Buffer.concat(chunks);

    const hex = CryptoJS.MD5(password).toString();
    const keyChunks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2) {
       keyChunks.push(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    }
    const key = Buffer.from(keyChunks);
    const decipher = new Rijndael(key, 'cbc');
    const decryptedPadded = decipher.decrypt(encryptedFile, 128, iv);
    //Remember to un-pad result
    const decrypted = padder.unpad(decryptedPadded, 32);
    const clearText = decrypted.toString('utf8');
    const paddedText = decryptedPadded.toString('utf16le');
    const plaidddnText = CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.stringify(decrypted);
    const testttt = crypto.createCipheriv("aes128", key, iv);
    const decrpyted = Buffer.concat([testttt.update(Buffer.from(encryptedFile)), testttt.final()]);
    const testdec = decrypted.toString();
    const bla = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedFile, key, { keySize: 16,  iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });
    const plainText = CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.stringify(bla);
}
```

When debugging both codes, I already manage that the byte arrays of the file (encdata in C#, encryptedFile in JS), and the byte arrays of iv and key are already the same, but somehow the final decryption is delivering different results. Anybody any ideas what I'm doing wrong in the final step?

Any help much appreciated! :)

Comment: When you try to encrypt on one language and decrypt on another, try matching word for word... I see a `Pkcs7` on the Javascript side... Do you see it on the C# side? And the final `Utf16LE`... How are you encoding the text on the C# side? There is even a Cbc... You are lucky and it is the default on .NET

Comment: You might want to read [Is a single md5 hash a good way to generate an AES key?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/is-a-single-md5-hash-a-good-way-to-generate-an-aes-key)

Comment: In the NodeJS code the ciphertext must be passed in `decipher.decrypt()`. `encryptedFile` however also contains the IV, i.e. the leading 16 bytes must therefore be removed (with `slice()`). The array of the `decrypt()` call must be converted to a buffer (with `Buffer.from()`). The block size to be used in `unpad()` is 16 bytes (consistent with the 128 bits used in `decrypt()`). The whole CryptoJS part that comes after the `clearText` line seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: You can now rate yourself as being officially awesome! Thanks so much! Unpadding to 16 bytes and of course the Buffer.from did the trick! :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out the solution is to change the unpadding to 16 bytes and decrypt from a Buffer:

```
    const decryptedPadded = Buffer.from(decipher.decrypt(encryptedFile, 128, iv));
    const decrypted = padder.unpad(decryptedPadded, 16);
    const clearText = decrypted.toString('utf16le');
```

Now I only need to remove the first few bytes with the IV :)